# jQuery not selecting every image

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts

I'm currently working on an userscript for a forum, however, it doesn't seem to work.
The forum has two themes, I want to replace the userbars (located in `/groupimages/`) from the new theme with the ones from the old theme.

I'm currently trying this:

```
$("img[src*='/groupimages/']").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("/modern_pl/", "/blackreign/"));
});
```

`/modern_pl/` is the directory of the new theme, `/blackreign/` of the old one.
An example URL of an image is `/images/modern_pl/groupimages/english/strange.gif`

It does select some pictures, but not all. It looks like it suddenly stops, without giving out any error message in Chromes JS-Console.
Lets say the `strange.gif` is there 3 times on the page, it only replaces it once. Some other pictures (that should be selected because the source contains `/groupimages/`) are completely ignored, so I doubt that this is happening because one picture is there more than once.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you sure whether all the img elements are present in the dom when this script is execute

Comment: Maybe use `console.log(this)` in the for each loop to count and see which images are caught and which aren't?

Comment: Does `$("img[src*='/groupimages/']").length` return the correct number?

Comment: Many things could be happening: AJAX, iframes, background images, `<base>` tag, `@import`ed CSS, etc.  **Link to a sample page.**

Answer (score 4):

To me the snippet looks good.

Did you place it inside a Document ready function? If not, the problem could be that the pictures just aren't yet loaded when the script runs.

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $("img[src*='/groupimages/']").each(function() {
        $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("/modern_pl/", "/blackreign/"));
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

Its hard to help when the code you present works.. but lets assume there is content loaded by ajax after the page loaded completely.
You could do this.. which is not nice at all.. but assuming you don't have further access to the code on the website, try this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("img[src*='/groupimages/']").each(function() {
        $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("/modern_pl/", "/blackreign/"));
    });
},1000);
```

This waits a second for other scripts to be loaded before running your code.

Comment: It is inside the Document ready function, but somehow this doesn't work. :/

Answer (score 0):

Something like that ?

```
var img = $( 'img' );
img.attr( 'src', img.attr( 'src' ).replace( "\/groupimages\/", "\/modern_pl\/") );
```

Comment: `img.attr( 'src' )` will return only the first image src